# Nginx - serve static website from a subfolder

Tags: nginx

I have a static app in a subfolder of a website:

```
URL: https://example.com/application

Files:
/home/username/web/application/public/index.html
/home/username/web/application/public/css/style.css
...
```

How to set proper 'locatin' in order to access the static files under the `public` folder?

I tried without success:

```
location /application/ {
       /home/username/web/application/public;
       index index.html;
}
```

```
location ^/application/(.*)$ {
       alias /home/username/web/application/public/$1;
       index index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
location /application {
   alias /home/username/web/application/public;
   index index.html; 
}
```